# How to programmatically create/build Sharepoint PPS -- Dashboard, Scorecard, KPIs

Tags: sharepoint, dashboard, performancepoint, kpi

Is there any ariticles or suggestions that can help me go through this: How to programmatically create/build Sharepoint PPS -- Dashboard, Scorecard, KPIs, and then dploy it or import it to a web page?

I am planning to create a `KPI` and conncted with a analytic service table, add such `kpi` to a scorecard, add scordcard to a dashboard. Finally, add such dashboard to the page(web page or web part page).

I hope MS allow me do the following:

```
KPI myKpi = new KPI(); 
Dashboard myDb = new DashBoard();
        .
        .
        .
myPage.import(myDb);
MyDb.visulization();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out the "Creating and Deploying Dashboards Remotely" blog post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2010/10/21/creating-and-deploying-dashboards-remotely.aspx

Also, the MSDN topics have code examples for the Create/Delete/Get/Update methods in the SPDataStore class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.performancepoint.scorecards.store.spdatastore_methods.aspx